# Issue with translation of static website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a static `html5` and `css3` website, which I want to translate. Primary language is German, and I want to translate it to English and Russian.

I found a jQuery plugin ([translate.js](http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/index.html)), which does exactly what I need but I have one issue with this plugin.

Everything works perfectly, when I use for example

HTML

```
<p class="trn">Herzlich Willkommen</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var t = {
    "Herzlich Willkommen": {
      en: "Welcome",
      ru: "Добро пожаловать"
    }
  };

  var _t = $('body').translate({
    lang: "de",
    t: t
  });

  var str = _t.g("translate");
  console.log(str);

  $(".lang_selector").click(function(ev) {
    var lang = $(this).attr("data-value");
    _t.lang(lang);

    console.log(lang);
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

but when I want to use nested `trn` class inside parent `trn` class, unfortunately I can not translate it.

For example:

```
<h2 class="trn">Ihr <span class="trn">Bauunternehmen</span> in <span class="trn">Wien</span></h2>
```

Can you help me please?

[Plugin documentation](https://github.com/tinoni/translate.js)

jQuery.translate.js

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.translate = function(options) {

    var that = this; //a reference to ourselves

    var settings = {
      css: "trn",
      lang: "en"
      /*,
      t: {
        "translate": {
          pt: "tradução",
          br: "tradução"
        }
      }
      */
    };
    settings = $.extend(settings, options || {});
    if (settings.css.lastIndexOf(".", 0) !== 0) //doesn't start with '.'
      settings.css = "." + settings.css;

    var t = settings.t;

    //public methods
    this.lang = function(l) {
      if (l) {
        settings.lang = l;
        this.translate(settings); //translate everything
      }
      return settings.lang;
    };


    this.get = function(index) {
      var res = index;

      try {
        res = t[index][settings.lang];
      } catch (err) {
        //not found, return index
        return index;
      }

      if (res)
        return res;
      else
        return index;
    };

    this.g = this.get;

    //main
    this.find(settings.css).each(function(i) {
      var $this = $(this);

      var trn_key = $this.attr("data-trn-key");
      if (!trn_key) {
        trn_key = $this.html();
        $this.attr("data-trn-key", trn_key); //store key for next time
      }

      $this.html(that.get(trn_key));
    });

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The plugin does not seem to support nested translation classes... And to be honnest, it's logical. Just avoid nesting.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion